# Python multiprocessing pool memory issue

Tags: python, memory

I want to run a python process that is always alive in the background monitoring if some XMLs are updated. However, I am getting python [defunct] after a while. I suspect it's memory related issue because I can see the memory for the child process keeps on growing. But I am not sure how to fix that. Here's the code:

```
def getXmlFile(url):    
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    rep = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    response_content = rep.read()
    last_modified = rep.info().getheader('Last-Modified')

    return (response_content, last_modified)

def writeXmlFile(content, fileName):
    file_path = os.path.join(OUTPUT, fileName)
    f = open(file_path, 'w')
    f.write(content)    
    f.close()

def downloadXml(xml):
    url = BASE_URL + xml
    (response, last_modified) = getXmlFile(url)

    if LAST_MODIFIED.get(xml) is None or LAST_MODIFIED[xml] != last_modified:
            LAST_MODIFIED[xml] = last_modified
            utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            currentTime = utc_datetime.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
            fileName = xml.replace('.XML', '_%s.XML' % currentTime)
            print "Writing " + fileName
            writeXmlFile(response, fileName)

def main():
    pool = Pool(processes=1)

    while (True):
        pool.map_async(downloadXml, XmlList)
        time.sleep(2)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Everything is working fine initially. It's monitoring certain xmls every 2 seconds and if there's an update, it will download the xml. But it will hang after a while. Ps aux would show the child python process with python [defunc].

Comment: I ... err ... I can't quite tell what you mean by "However, I am getting python after a while."  Do you get a traceback?  Any errors at all?

Comment: sorry, it seems like stackoverflow does not like certain symbols. I get python [defunct] after a while and the main process just hangs there without any error.

Comment: You left out the code for `monitorXmlFunction()`.

Comment: It's actually downloadXml(). Sorry fixed.